# You must set config.secret_key_base in your app's config error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I know this has been asked before, but I have tried all the solutions suggested in other answer feeds.

My config/initializers/secret_token.rb file contains the following:

```
secret = Rails.env.production? ? ENV['SECRET_TOKEN'] : "top_secret_token"
SampleApp::Application.config.secret_key_base = secret
```

I ran:

```
heroku config:set SECRET_TOKEN=e6b2d0e35664326d2a...
```

I then ran:

```
heroku open
```

and got this error:

```
You must set config.secret_key_base in your app's config.
```

This is my .gitignore file:

```
# See https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files for more about ignoring files.
#
# If you find yourself ignoring temporary files generated by your text editor
# or operating system, you probably want to add a global ignore instead:
#   git config --global core.excludesfile '~/.gitignore_global'

# Ignore bundler config.
/.bundle

# Ignore the default SQLite database.
/db/*.sqlite3
/db/*.sqlite3-journal

# Ignore all logfiles and tempfiles.
/log/*.log
/tmp

# Ignore other unneeded files.
database.yml
doc/
*.swp
*~
.project
.DS_Store 
.idea
.secret
```

Comment: post here your secrets.yml

Comment: I'm using Rails 4.0.8 before the new version that uses secrets.yml so I don't have that file... I'm following the Michael Hartl ruby on rails tutorial if that helps!

Comment: as an option you can consider upgrading to newest rails version..

Comment: hmm the only problem is that the tutorial is designed for 4.0 not 4.1 and it doesn't work with the newest rails version

Answer (score -1):

Have you added `config/initializers/secret_token.rb` to the repository and pushed it to heroku?

Comment: you better delete this, 'cause it is not an answer.